# How does shifting Product/Divide Block work?

Tags: control, transfer-function, math

I've just learned about PID MRAC using MIT Rule, and to build it in Simulink I need to use the Product/Divide Block.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/product.html

[image]

This is a figure from "Automatic Tuning of PID Controllers Using Model Reference Adaptive Control Techniques" paper by K. Pirabakaran and V. M. Becerra.

If I try to shift the pointed product block above to the left, the Kp or the output on the right will be messed up.

---

Let me simplify the problem by this block diagram.

[image]

---

Here is the output on the scope

[image]

The first block output (ya), output the same as the second block (yb).

---

I expect four of them to be the same.

$$y_a(t)=y_b(t)=y_c(t)=y_d(t)$$

With its transfer function combined altogether.

$$\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{1}{(s+1)(s+1)(s+1)} $$

---

How does it happened? I expect the product blocks to be working as transfer function multiplication. Am I wrong? Does it exist in the Simulink library then of what I've been expecting?

---

**Add info as per comments**

I'm using MATLAB R2018b Update 5 and I've also tried using ode14x, ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, ode5, and ode8 solver with fixed 1 ms time step. Even also tried to use the [convolution block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/convolution.html) with 3 different computation method. The result still the same.

Suppose if my expectation above wrong that product block will act as a transfer function multiplication, then

$$Y_a(s)=\frac{1}{s} \cdot \frac{1}{(s+1)^3}$$

and

$$Y_b(s) = Y_c(s) = Y_d(s) = \frac{1}{s^2} \cdot \frac{1}{(s+1)^3}$$

But, as we see from the simulation \$Y_a(t) = Y_b(t)\$ and \$Y_b(t) \ne Y_c(s) \ne Y_d(s)\$.

So what's wrong?

Comment: Multiplication in time domain equals convolution in the frequency (Laplace) domain. So, you cannot simply multiply like you do. You'd have to use convolution with the multiply blocks.

Comment: Another thing, your input is not a constant in the s-domain, it's actually a step function , i.e. 1/s

Comment: @Ben The only way I think about it is this $$Y_a(s) = \frac{1}{s} \cdot \frac{1}{(s+1)^3}$$ and $$Y_b(s) = Y_c(s) = Y_d(s) = \frac{1}{s^2} \cdot \frac{1}{(s+1)^3}$$ Is it correct? Do you mean that if I couid change the product block with convolution block it will work?

Comment: @Ben Any further information?

Comment: I didn't have enough time to look at it. B, c and D should yield the same result. Perhaps you have a made a mistake in the simulation?

Comment: @Ben I really appreciate for your kindness by using your precious time. No I haven't made a mistake, every settings is on default. I still don't understand why it happened.

Comment: Multiplication in the time domain is convolution in the s-domain. You should try to work out the maths...

Comment: @Ben Yes I understood that. But what I don't understand is that why b, c, and d output are not the same and why ya = yb?

Comment: Maybe your step size? Solver?

Comment: @Ben I'm using MATLAB R2018b Update 5 and I've just tried using ode14x, ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, ode5, and ode8 solver with 1 ms time step. Even also tried to use the [convolution block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/convolution.html) with 3 different computation method. The result still the the same.

Comment: @Ben Any further ideas?

Comment: Replace your constant by a sine wave, what will the output frequency of the output be in the 4 cases? In 3 cases you will modulate a sine wave with another some wave, thus generating 2 frequencies